# Can't apply SASS styling to my view in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sass, view

I have a problem with styling, I have created some simple styling (scss file):

```
body {
    background: red;
}
.mobile-app {
    background: red;
}
```

I have created my first view ever like that :

```
@model AppLearn.ViewModels.BooksListViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>CRUD For Learning Purposes Only</title>
        <link href="~/content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mobile-app">
            @foreach (var book in Model.Books)
            {
                <div class="book-card">
                    <div class="book-card__image"></div>
                    <div class="book-card__title">
                        <h1>@book.bookName</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book-card__actions"></div>
                </div>
            }
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it is not working!

I added the `runat="server"` based on a response found already here in the stack that fixed someone else problem, but did not to mine.

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `runat="server"` is definitely **NOT** applicable here - that's very old, legacy **webforms** stuff - does not work / apply to ASP.NET MVC ...

Comment: I have removed it, it was not working even without it

Comment: what is the solution then ?

Comment: Are you compiling your sass via a task runner or an extension first?

Comment: I did exactly what I said in the question itself, I don't know what task runner or extension first do and what's those anyway ! I am new to this tech !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to compile sass with visual studio is via the `WebCompiler` extension.

Download and install from the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler).

Now, after installing the extension and restarting Visual Studio you have to options:

1. You can either compile your files manually via the added context menu option (right click on file):

   [image]
2. Or simply let the extension handle the compilation on save:
   When you compile a sass file for the first time the extension creates a `compilerconfig.json` file which will store your input and output files like this:

   ```json
   [
     {
       "outputFile": "wwwroot/css/app.css",
       "inputFile": "wwwroot/sass/main.scss"
     }
   ]
   ```

Now the extension will start watching the `inputFile` for changes and once you save a change it will compile and output to the `outputFile` path.

You can edit your input and output paths to match where you want your output files to be stored.

For more complex scenarios see [MSDN for bundling and minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1#choose-a-bundling-and-minification-strategy). Its a great resource on using Gulp in Visual Studio.